# Using one class from another class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I wrote a simple program to read through a log and to parse through and obtain the lowest beginning number (the head) and to print it. I am now editing that program and combining it with a class I wrote to parse an actual logfile. Essentially, as opposed to sorting based off of the simple number from the log from my previous program, I now need to reference the parsed information from one class into another class. I was wondering what the most convenient way to do this. I am a beginner programmer in python and don't know if I can explicitly reference the class.

Here are the classes.

Parser

```
class LogLine:

    SEVERITIES = ['EMERG','ALERT','CRIT','ERR','WARNING','NOTICE','INFO','DEBUG']
    severity = 1


    def __init__(self, line):
        try:
            m = re.match(r"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),?(\d{3}),?(\s+\[(?:[^\]]+)\])+\s+[A-Z]+\s+(\s?[a-zA-Z0-9\.])+\s?(\((?:\s?\w)+\))\s?(\s?.)+", line)
            timestr, msstr, sevstr, self.filename, linestr, self.message = m.groups()
            self.line = int(linestr)
            self.sev = self.SEVERITIES.index(sevstr)
            self.time = float(calendar.timegm(time.strptime(timestr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"))) + float(msstr)/1000.0
            dt = datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
        except Exception:
            print 'error',self.filename


    def get_time(self):
        return self.time
    def get_severity(self):
        return self.sev
    def get_message(self):
        return self.message
    def get_filename(self):
        return self.filename
    def get_line(self):
        return self.line
```

Sorter

```
class LogFile:

    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self.logfile = open(filepath, "r")
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "x=" + str(self.x) + "y="+str(self.y)

    def readline(self):
        if self.head != None:
            h = self.head
            self.head = None
            return h
        else:
            return self.logfile.readline().rstrip(' ')

    def get_line(self):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.readline().rstrip(' ')
            return self.head.get.line()
        else:
            return self.head.get.line()

    def close (self):
        self.logfile.close()
```

I have begun to edit my second class by adding the get_line function. Don't know if I'm on the right track.

In simpler terms, I need the head to become "LogLine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to use one class from another class.  You have one class that parses a single line from a log file and builds an object that represents the line; and you have another class that reads lines from a log file.  It would be very natural for the second class to call the first class.

Here is a very simple class that reads all lines from a log file and builds a list:

```
class LogFile(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            self.lst = [LogLine(line) for line in f]
```

You can see that `self.lst` is being set to a list of lines from the input log file, but not just the text of the line; the code is calling `LogLine(line)` to store instances of `LogLine`.  If you want, you can sort the list after you build it:

```
self.lst.sort(key=LogLine.get_line)
```

If the log files are very large, it might not be practical to build the list.  You have a `.get_line()` method function, and we can use that:

```
class LogFile(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self.logfile = open(filepath, "r")

    def get_line(self):
        try:
            line = next(self.logfile)  # get next line from open file object
            return LogLine(line)
        except StopIteration:  # next() raises this when you reach the end of the file
            return None  # return 

    def close(self):
        self.logfile.close()
```

An open file object (returned by the `open()` function) can be iterated.  We can call `next()` on this object and it will give us the next input line.  When the end of file is reached, Python will raise `StopIteration` to signal the end of the file.

Here the code will catch the `StopIteration` exception and return `None` when the end of the log file is reached.  But I think this isn't the best way to handle this problem.  Let's make the LogFile class work in `for` loops and such:

```
class LogFile(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self.f = open(filepath)

    def __next__(self):  # Python 3.x needs this to be named "__next__"
        try:
            line = next(self.f)
            return LogLine(line)
        except StopIteration:
            # when we reach the end of input, close the file object
            self.f.close()
            # re-raise the exception
            raise
    next = __next__  # Python 2.x needs this to be named "next"
```

A `for` loop in Python will repeatedly call the `.__next__()` method function (Python 3.x) or else the `.next()` method function (Python 2.x) until the `StopIteration` exception is raised.  Here we have defined both method function names so this code should work in Python 2.x or in Python 3.x.

Now you can do this:

```
for ll in LogFile("some_log_file"):
    ... # do something with ll, which will always be a LogLine instance
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks for the clear answer. To follow up, can I call a class method from outside the class? For example, I have written a function to find the lowest t.
`def get_line_with_lowest_t(logs):
    lowest_i = -1
    for i in range(len(logs)):
        t = logs[i].get_t()
        if lowest_i == -1 or t < lowest_t:
            lowest_i = i
            lowest_t = t
    if lowest_i != -1:
        return logs[i].get_line()
    else:
        return None`
As you can see I've called "get_line" Is this valid?
Bad formatting - picture : http://imgur.com/U2x38

Comment: Yes, if `logs` is a list of `LogLine` instances, then you can use `logs[i].get_line()` to call the `.get_line()` method function on the instance stored at position `i` in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps look over my code for coherency? If somethings wrong, you don't need to fix it. I'm really more concerned with learning how to structure right now. Could shoot you an e-mail with the pastebin link. If not, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of time for today to post on StackOverflow.  And this question is really a request for a code review.  Why don't you try posting your code on the Code Review site?  I hope you will get some useful feedback there.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had no idea this site existed. You've helped me immensely thanks again.